# Is there a stackless and heapless programming language?

Tags: stackless

Is there a statically compiled programming language that is both stackless and heapless?

For data, such a language would not have a concept of memory allocation. Instead, the memory requirements of the program would be known completely at compile-time.

For code, there would not be a concept of call stack. There could be functions, but they'd be inlined at every call site.

I am specifically interested by portable languages with some form of implementation or a compiler that produces native binaries.

Answer (score 0):

Pure x86 machine language fits your stackless and heapless constraints(within real mode constraints).  Portability is not possible, unless the compiler has access to **every** memory location for all hardware IO(memory locations) that are **Fixed** for **all** supported platforms(this condition excludes all dynamic interfaces including PlugandPlay, USB, and PCI/PCIE busses)

It is completely possible to create such a structure within severe hardware limits(every device must be compiled in and allocated at boot, as in older computers like the c64 or Apple II) but **all** functionality must be pre-compiled into the OS, as in every **program possible** that is to run on the platform.

This is not a general computing platform anymore. Program a micro-controller, GPU, or ASIC to solve the task instead.

Comment: I guess that for syscalls, there is no other choice than to use the stack.

But I wonder if it wouldn't be possible to impose all the constraints in a language and have it compile a regular executable that an OS can run.